# Type of first element in a column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

i have a table in pandas df

```
id   count
1     100
2     200
3     300
```

i want to find what is the first value under id column

i.e '1' and the type of '1'

can i use?

```
type(df['id'][0])
```

but it is not giving me right result.

it tried using this too.

```
type(df.loc[df.index[0], 'id'].head(1))
```

Any ideas how to get the first row value in a column in pandas df

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need:

```
print (df)
   id  count
0   1    100
1   2    200
2   3    300

#if first index is 0
print (type(df.loc[0, 'id']))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Or better is select first value in column `id` by [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) or [`Series.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html):

```
print (type(df['id'].iat[0]))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
print (type(df['id'].iloc[0]))
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

`iat` is faster:

```
In [64]: %timeit (type(df['id'].iat[0]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 10.6 µs per loop

In [65]: %timeit (type(df['id'].iloc[0]))
100000 loops, best of 3: 16.9 µs per loop
```

Comment: `yes`, but `iloc` is slowier as `iat`

Comment: oh! i didn't knew that, thanks , also look at my comment i posted on your answer on my previous question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41142726/complex-map-operation-on-two-dataframes-in-pandas-with-condition/41142886?noredirect=1#comment69517529_41142886)